# Segmentation fault in opencv copyTo

Tags: c++, opencv

Since opencv builtin padding function doens't work for any multidimensional matrix i had to write it by my own :

```
cv::Mat PadImage(const cv::Mat& input, int pad_h, int pad_w)
{
    int padded_size[3];
    padded_size[0] = input.size[0] + 2 * pad_h;
    padded_size[1] = input.size[1] + 2 * pad_w;
    padded_size[2] = input.size[2];

    cv::Range ranges[3];
    ranges[0] = cv::Range(pad_h, padded_size[0] - pad_h);
    ranges[1] = cv::Range(pad_w, padded_size[1] - pad_w);
    ranges[2] = cv::Range(0, input.size[2]);

    cv::Mat input_padded(3, padded_size, input.type(), 0);
    // segmentation fault here at this call !
    input.copyTo(input_padded(ranges));
    return input_padded;
}
```

I assume the input matrix has 3 dimensions, and the padding is done only in dimensions 1&2.

When i call this function with different types of matrices i get segmentation fault (at the line where copyTo is called) and i can't figure out why. 
Example of test code :

```
int size[3] = {61, 29, 32};
cv::Mat X(3, size, CV_8UC1, 0);
cv::Mat X_ = PadImage(X, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You triggered the wrong constructor for `cv::Mat`, when you are trying to initialize the matrix with 0, always remember there is another constructor which takes a raw pointer

```
Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, const size_t* steps=0);
```

So if you correct the following two lines, you should be able to get what you want

```
cv::Mat input_padded(3, padded_size, input.type(), cv::Scalar(0));
cv::Mat X(3, size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```